# Docker Secret to env variable of database string connection Not being parsed/recognized by sql alchemy

Tags: docker, sqlalchemy, environment-variables, string-concatenation, docker-secrets

I'm trying to hide some sensitive information about my application with docker secrets.
I did great in most of them but I'm having trouble with the env of the database connection.

When I pass the string to connect the database through the secrets, I get this error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'db_lang_driverdb_userdb_passworddb_hostdb_database'`

I created the secrets in .txt files at my local machine.

This is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  stripe:
    image: stripe-full-env
    container_name: stripe
    ports:
      - "7000:7000"
    secrets:
      - stripe-secret-key
      - db_lang_driver
      - db_user
      - db_password
      - db_host
      - db_database
    environment:
      - STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=stripe-secret-key
      - DB_LANG_DRIVER=db_lang_driver
      - DB_USER=db_user
      - DB_PASSWORD=db_password
      - DB_HOST=db_host
      - DB_DATABASE=db_database
secrets:
  stripe-secret-key:
    file: ./stripe-secret-key.txt
  db_lang_driver:
    file: ./db_lang_driver.txt
  db_user:
    file: ./db_user.txt
  db_password:
    file: ./db_password.txt
  db_host: 
    file: ./db_host.txt
  db_database:
    file: ./db_database.txt
```

ALL of the ENV variables except the `STRIPE_SECRET_KEY`, are from the database connection string that I'm concatenating at the code written in python. The stripe-secret-key secret is doing ok. But when the code need to access the `strConnection2`, it doesn't get the information that is being passed by the secrets.

```
strConnection2 = os.getenv('DB_LANG_DRIVER') + os.getenv('DB_USER') + os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD') + os.getenv('DB_HOST') + os.getenv('DB_DATABASE')


if strConnection2 == None:
    raise TypeError("Database string not found")

engine = create_engine(
    strConnection2, 
    echo=False, 
    pool_recycle=900, 
    pool_pre_ping=True, 
    pool_size=1000,
    max_overflow=2000
)
```

I tried to use external and file secrets. Both showed the sql alchemy error.

Important. The same string when used in Dockerfile works fine to connect the database.

- I tried using the string not concatenated with one long env variable.
- Tried using the concatenated string with multiple env variables
- Used external secrets in Swarm trough docker secret create
- Used secrets created manually at my local machine

Comment: The values in the environment are the literal values from the docker compose file, for example `B_LANG_DRIVER` -> `db_lang_driver`.  So your docker compose file isn't picking up the values from the environment.  Are they being set?

Comment: I think so. I'm trying to pass them trough secrets that are created in a directory called "docker-secrets" in my root project folder. The fact that they have literally equal names is just for convenience.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Did you find a way ? Thx

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

The problem is that you are trying to assign to environment variables the **contents** of secrets, whereas in fact, they are just assigned the **names** of secretes.

For example:
Let's say that the value of the secrete `db_user` is  `gustavo`. And when you're try to assign it's value to the environment variable `DB_USER` in docker-compose, you are getting `DB_USER=db_user`, but **not** `DB_USER=gustavo`.

#### Solution

By default all secrets in a container are stored as a file in the following location: `/run/secrets/<secret_name>`.
So, you can try to read content of these files in your program.

Comment: This seems like a brute-force solution. How could OP achieve what they are trying to do through the YAML configuration (and listed txt files)?